# Request with namespace not accepted by SOAPUI mockservice

Tags: soap, namespaces, soapui, mockserver

Could someone help in ignoring the wsdl validation while receiving in SOAPUI. Actually I have two method of same request

```
Method 1:Generated out of SOAPUI using WSDL
--------
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">  <soapenv:Body>
<perfmonCollectCounterData>     
<Host></Host>
<Object></Object>
</perfmonCollectCounterData>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Method 2: This is with namespace
-------
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns1:PerfmonCollectCounterData soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap/">        
<Host xsi:type="xsd:string"></Host>
<Object xsi:type="ns1:ObjectNameType"></Object>
</ns1:PerfmonCollectCounterData>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Actually I would like to get the response for the method2 request .Its failing the validation of WSDL. Could someone please help in igonoring the validation or how to handle mock service of SOAPUI to respond for given method2 request . I could get the response for Method-1

*Updating the question from comment to make it clear*

The error what we see in the soapUI response is this :

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body> 
        <soapenv:Fault> 
            <faultcode>Server</faultcode> 
            <faultstring>Missing operation for soapAction [schemas.cisco.com/ast/soap/action/… and body element [perfmonCollectCounterData] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]</faultstring> 
        </soapenv:Fault> 
    </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Did you added schema compliance assertion and that is why its failing? then please remove schema compliance. assertion. by the way question is not clear .

Comment: In SOAPUI , I have mocked the SOAP server . I am trying to send  Method2 request to the mock service , it is responding with fault response . I have not added any assertion to the mockservice

Comment: look at this https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/R-Missing-operation-for-soapAction-and-body-element-moc/m-p/38006#M15297

Comment: If the wsdl is correct, I believe that it would not happen. Please check with your team if the wsdl is right.